# How to send queries through websocket using json and receive response from server php websocket?

Tags: php, jquery, websocket

I am looking for a solution for reducing server connections through WebSockets. I have studied some of the examples but most are of chat applications.

I want to send queries like user login, registration, get product list, add to cart, update cart etc through the socket connection established to the server and receive results through the socket. So that for every single query it doesn't hit the server. Once the browser is opened in client system or mobile it will open only one socket connection through which all his transactions will be done.

Any idea how to do this?

I am executing below code in localhost:

HTML Code:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket;
function init() {
var host = "ws://127.0.0.1:9000/echobot"; // SET THIS TO YOUR SERVER
try {
socket = new WebSocket(host);
//    log('WebSocket - status '+socket.readyState);
socket.onopen    = function(msg) { 
//    log("Welcome - status "+this.readyState); 
};
socket.onmessage = function(msg) { 
//    log("Received: "+msg.data); 
};
socket.onclose   = function(msg) { 
//    log("Disconnected - status "+this.readyState); 
};
}

catch(ex){ 
//    log(ex); 
alert(ex);
}

$("#msg").focus();
}

function send(){
var msg = $("#msg").val();
if(!msg) { 
alert("Message can not be empty"); 
return; 
}
$("#msg").val("");
$("#msg").focus();

doLogin(msg);
}

/* This ajax I don't want to execute as it hits the server, rather want to send data through the socket */

function doLogin(email, callback){
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url: "test.php",
data : {email:email    },
datatype : 'html',
success : function(response){
try { 
socket.send(email); 
log('Received: '+response); 
} catch(ex) { 
log(ex); 
}
}
});
}


function log(msg){ 
var html=$("#log").html();
if(html){
html = html + "<br>";    
}
$("#log").html(html + msg);
}

</script>

</head>
<body onload="init()">
<h3>WebSocket v2.00</h3>
<div id="log"></div>
<input id="msg" type="textbox" />
<button onclick="send()">Send</button>
<button onclick="quit()">Quit</button>
<button onclick="reconnect()">Reconnect</button>
```

Thanks

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: It matters not what kind of requests you're sending to the server. Whether it's for chat, login or add item to card, you'll always do everything in the same way. Open connection, send actions/commands, process request on the server, receive data in desired format and process it.

Comment: Well I am updating the code I have written in my question. Kindly guide me how to take it forward.

Comment: `So that for every single query it doesn't hit the server.` - That's not how it works. It will hit the server still, but with WebSocket message instead of HTTP request.